# How to change image url on all pages after migration with out using a plugin in wordpress?

Tags: database, wordpress, url, migration, file-transfer

After migration, all of images on pages (about-us, artists etc) are not showing I have to manually change them just like what I did on the home page. I have tried different plugin such as velvet blues and search and replace but it couldn't change the images on pages by automatic instead i have to do them manual which would a lot of time.

Here's what I like to happen with all the image tag on all pages, I want the url http://cjdrafts.info/quadrantgallery to change to http://cjdrafts.info/art

```
<img  src="http://cjdrafts.info/quadrantgallery/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/237715.jpg" align="center" />
```

change to

```
<img  src="http://cjdrafts.info/art/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/237715.jpg" align="center" />
```

I have been changing urls manually on all of my other drafts after migration for all pages so it will be great if someone can teach me how i can do it automatically.

THanks in advance.

Comment: to simplify, I'd use a custom .htaccess rewrite rule.

Comment: Hi pedro! Thanks for your reply. Can you teach me on how to do that. I would really appreciate that

Answer (score 2):

1.) I understand that you've said that you don't want to use a WordPress plugin, but if possible you really ought to checkout [better search replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search/) it should do exactly what you're describing.

2.) You could run this SQL code in your database management system:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://cjdrafts.info/quadrantgallery', 'http://cjdrafts.info/art') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://cjdrafts.info/quadrantgallery','http://cjdrafts.info/art');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://cjdrafts.info/quadrantgallery', 'http://cjdrafts.info/art');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://cjdrafts.info/quadrantgallery','http://cjdrafts.info/art');
```

Comment: Hi A. Campbell, tried that plugin better search but it didnt change all the urls particularly in img urls in pages. Or i may have done something wrong.  I will try your SQL code tomorrow and will give you an update. Thanks for your help.

Comment: ill just upvote this since it helped my case over here in 2022 :) The thing to take into account however: when replacing `meta_value`, the `meta_value` holds the subfolder of the wp-content, so unless you are moving a website from a subfolder to the root of the domain, there may not be anything to replace here.